# Calling a custom Ribbon button in another Application from VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email

Normally my google skills aren't this bad.  I am looking for a way to send an email with VBA and selecting a ribbon button.  Basically I have a custom Ribbon button to encrypt emails, and I want it toggled on when the new email is created from VBA.  I have been unable to find any samples.  Any help would be appreciated

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outapp As Outlook.Application

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set outapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = outapp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "Email@place.thing"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "BACON"
    .HTMLBody = "TESTING"
    ' .Send
    .Display
End With

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set outapp = Nothing
End Sub
```

So when a new email is created I want the "Encrypt" button pressed (see picture below) .  It is a toggle button.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWwgO.png

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: It works, but I am missing a component I don't know how to add.  New emails have a button on the ribbon I want selected through VBA.  As I mentioned above.

Comment: What is the callback procedure for the ribbon button, and does it take any required arguments?

Comment: You're doing this from Excel, to Outlook, and trying to invoke a procedure that is tied to the Outlook ribbon?  That might be a bit more complicated... but at minimum still need to see the callback procedure's information as requested above. Showing the relevant snippets of the Outlook Add-in's VBA and XML might also help.

Comment: ill clarify in an edit

Comment: The screenshot is illustrative, but not otherwise helpful. It provides no context that would help me tell you how to call it programmatically. For that, I would need the information previously requested: the Add-in's CustomUI XML and also the associated VBA callback procedure.

Comment: Did you try using Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show?

Comment: I honestly have no idea where to find those things, the button was not added by something I wrote but rather is added from the Entrust program being installed.  Any hints on where to find this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. I am able to successfully invoke a ribbon button's procedure in an external application (tested in PPT because I don't have a readily available Outlook Add-in with customUI, but same approach should work for Outlook, Word, etc.)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub CallExternalRibbon(app As Object, _
                           AddInName as String, _
                           ModuleName As String, _
                           ProcedureName As String)

       '### 
       '    runs a specific procedure from another application/Add-in
       '    AddInName is the name of the Add-in's VBAProject
       '    ModuleName should NOT use Option Private Module
       '    ProcedureName should be declared Public
       '    
       '    May also require change to application's Trust Center settings
       '        (specifically: allow access to VBAProject Object Model)
       '###

        Dim externalProcedure As String

       '## concatenate the procedure string
        externalProcedure = AddInName & "!" & ModuleName & "." & ProcedureName

        '## run the external procedure from that application
        app.Run externalProcedure


    End Sub
```

Call this like so, before the `.Send`. Modify the string arguments to your specific needs:

```
Call CallExternalRibbon(outApp, _
                        "AddIn_VBAProject_Name", _
                        "Module_Name", _
                        "Callback_Procedure_Name")
```

**NOTES:**

Not thoroughly tested, but works in simple cases. You may run in to some issues by starting a process thread in another application.

This will work for an Add-in that is created with CustomUI and XML/VBA callbacks. It may not work and has not been tested on any proprietary Add-in or other COM Add-in that you might have installed from a third party.

Comment: I am not able to get this working, maybe I am not understanding something but "externalProcedure"... no idea what that would be

Comment: `externalProcedure` is a string that will identify the Outlook macro that needs to be run. It is built from the three string arguments passed to the `CallExternalRibbon` procedure.  In the third-to-last paragraph I describe how to `Call` this function, and indicate also that you need to modify the `Call` statement to include your project's specific name, module name, and procedure name.

Comment: didn't you call that "proc" in the line above?

Comment: crap. Yes that is a typo.  change it to `proc` in that line, or just use the revised answer I updated above. My mistake!!

Comment: Thanks David, I am sure your solution works, however the idiot trying to use it [me] does not know the components that make up that string, or where to find them.  The button that I am trying to activate is not a custom VB macro, its part of a software called ENTRUST.  don't know if that changes thing, Could you by chance point me in the direction to find these items?

Comment: Yes they does change things and is exactly the exception that I describe (third party software). Unless they've provided an API, I think you're out of luck here. Do they have any online documentation? ?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I looked up the docs they have on it, and it seems as though they lock it out intestinally.  I also tried accessing through the commandbars, with no luck.  Oh well appreciate all the help

Comment: Right. Third party add-ins like that wouldn't be accessible through CommandBars and unless they specifically expose some methods through an API, you won't be able to do it through RibbonUI/VBA, either :(

Comment: How are you supposed to get the module and procedure name?